# How to restrict Visual Studio 2012.2 from generating .css files in LESS editor?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, less

When you save .less files in Visual Studio 2012.2, LESS editor generates corresponding .css files.

I need to disable this functionality, since I want only to have .less files under source control and in the project's file list (.csproj).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Menu > Tools > Options > Web Essentials > LESS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set .css files in a specific directory to be ignored from your version control system. Each system has his own way to be told to ignore files, so if you want to follow this way you should better tell us what VCS are you using, or search for this functionality on your own.

Comment: Ignoring files won't help, since they are still gonna be present in the project (in .csproj file)